# Do elasticsearch queries touch the DB?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

Just starting to use elasticsearch with haystack in django using postgres, and I'm pretty happy with it so far.

I'm wondering if the search queries (filters) through ES will submit a query to the DB or do they use data gathered during indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I can delete the data in the DB and still search, the answer seems to be yes, the queries do not touch the DB but only touch the index.

Also, I found this documentation on the matter:
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/best_practices.html#avoid-hitting-the-database

Further, this is also from [the docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html?highlight=contains#stored-indexed-fields):

> For example, one great way to leverage this is to pre-rendering an
>   object’s search result template DURING indexing. You define an
>   additional field, render a template with it and it follows the main
>   indexed record into the index. Then, when that record is pulled when
>   it matches a query, you can simply display the contents of that field,
>   which avoids the database hit.: